# How to enable a button only when all the buttons are pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, button

Lets say I have six buttons in an app and I want to enable a seventh button only if all the six buttons were clicked. How do I achieve this in Xcode 9?

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you facing ?

Comment: @LeoDabus I . am creating a simple lottery app and I want to enable a button which takes the user to another view only after all the slots are scratched off? The slots are scratched off by clicking buttons

Comment: SO just create an array with 6 elements and set all of them to false. Every time the users clicks a button change the respective element to true and check if your array contains false. If it doesn't just go to the next view controller

Comment: @LeoDabus please give me an example on how to create an array and set elements to false.

Comment: You can just tag your buttons from 0 to 5 and use the button tag as the index of your array elements.

Comment: Sorry buddy this is not how SO works. This is not a code writing service. Try what I said and if you don't succeed edit your question and post your attempt with the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as a starting point for you.

(1). Create The Following Arrays:

```
//1. Create An Array To Store The Buttons
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()

//2. Create An Array Of Bools So We Can Determine Which Buttons Have Been Pressed
var buttonCheckArray = [false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

(2). Generate The Buttons:

```
 /// Creates 7 Buttons & Adds Them To The Screen
func createButtons(){

    for index in 0 ..< 7{

        //1. Create The Button
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (index * 100) + index * 10, y: 200 , width: 100, height: 100))
        button.setTitle("\(index)", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.tag = index
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        print(index)

        //2. Add The Button To The Button Array
        buttonArray.append(button)

        //3. Disable The Final Button
        if button.tag == 6 {
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }

        //4. Add The Button To The View
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

}
```

(3). Create The Validation Function:

```
/// Determines Which Button Has Been Pressed & Adjusts The buttonCheckArray
///
/// - Parameter sender: UIButton
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){

    //1. Get The Button Tag
    let buttonPressedIndex = sender.tag

    //2. Change The Background Colour
    sender.backgroundColor = .purple

    //3. Change The Bool Value In The Array For The Six Buttons
    if sender.tag != 6{
        buttonCheckArray[buttonPressedIndex] = true
    }


    if buttonCheckArray.contains(false){
        print("Not All 6 Buttons Have Been Selected")
    }else{
        print("All 6 Buttons Have Been Selected")

        guard let finalButton = buttonArray.last else { return }
        finalButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

}
```

Comment: Spoon-feeding newbies code is counterproductive. The OP is likely to copy/paste this code without understanding it. Better to post an outline of the solution and let the OP figure out how to put that online into code.